# To freeze or not to freeze?

Tags: storage-method, freezing, lasagna

I made a lasagna today (Thursday) that will be served on Sunday evening. What will yield a fresher-tasting result: refrigerating or freezing? I know that lasagna keeps in the fridge for about 3-5 days, and this is about 72 hours, but will it taste better/fresher if I freeze immediately after baking?

Comment: Thursday - Sunday is three days so 72 hours. Or did you mean to serve it on Saturday?

Comment: @Mien, even more than 72h as it's not evening yet...

Comment: @Mien - sorry, I can't do math :) I'll update.

Comment: @BaffledCook - it is evening over here :) And it's still in the oven...

Comment: OK, I didn't have a clue :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a rather long timescale, but you already made the thing.

I would put it in the freezer for 24 hours, the leave it in the fridge to thaw. That should be right on target for Sunday, without having to worry about infringing any guidelines.

Answer (score 8):

Rather than freezing it after baking, I would assemble the lasagna and freeze it today and then bake it on Sunday. It is rather difficult to reheat a whole baked lasagna from frozen without getting soggy noodles.

Comment: I have frozen lasagna often with no soggy effect... Although I usually do undercook it slightly when planning to freeze

Comment: I do this same sort of thing when making eggplant parmesan.

Comment: You get the soggy effect if you make the pasta yourself. If you buy sheets in a packet, that stuff doesn't get soggier.